# How can I reset or find password for my Admin in Active Admin panel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, activeadmin

How can I reset or change password for my Admin in active admin panel?
I am doing rails app and I made an admin account, but I don't remember the password so I want to change it to be able to log in,
I can't use 'forget your password'? button, because I set email like 'admin@paulina.com', so this email doesn't exist anywhere.

Comment: Do you have access to the rails console? If yes, you can change the password from there.

Comment: Is this on a development or production environment? In case of development, you indeed could use ```rails c``` to enter the console and e.g. do this: ```au=AdminUser.find_by(:email=>'admin@paulina.com');au.password='shouldntbetthateasy';au.save``` You could also use sql to update the database table to set a valid email. But then you need to b sure that sending e-mail from your app works. Good luck.